# Producing a database of addresses from OSM data on Windows

Tags: database, postgresql, openstreetmap

**What I want to accomplish**

I am interested in obtaining a database of addresses from the UK (postcode, street name, number, town, county, geocode).

**What I think is the right way of doing it**

I think what I need to do is download osm files for UK (for example, [here](http://nick.dev.openstreetmap.org/downloads/planet/)) and import them into a database with the osm2pgsql command. After some processing on this imported database, I will hopefully have address information that I can extract from the database.

**How I need your help**

Can this be done on the Windows operating system (i.e. osm2pgsql)? If so, does anyone have an idea on how this can be done in Windows, and perhaps if I can import this into an SQL database (or csv file)?

I know I can buy something similar to what I need from the [Post Office](http://www2.royalmail.com/marketing-services/address-management-unit/address-data-products/postcode-address-file-paf), but of course, I'd prefer not to pay or to have restrictive licenses on the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

osm2pgsql does exist in Windows, see the wiki https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql#Windows
(but seems you'd have to use Cygwin).

Otherwise you could find a way to achieve your result through processing via Osmosis, a java program. See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmosis

If you want data in points you could filter for the tags, convert the geometries to their centroid, then convert in the desired format.